# problem with background of ALL kivy widgets. Working from wsl2

Tags: background, kivy, default, default-value, wsl-2

I am starting with `kivy` from `wsl2`. My problem with the Framework is that an annoying background image always appears in ALL the widgets (`Button`, `TextInput`, etc.).
[image: image allways appears]

Comment: Problems like this have often turned out to be due to bad graphics drivers. Do you have the latest drivers for your hardware?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the graphical environment of wsl2. upgrade to windows 11 trying to fix the problem but it persists